# How can I run the Kotlin REPL kotlinc-jvm or kotlinc

Tags: kotlin, read-eval-print-loop

I am completely new to Kotlin, and I am trying to run the Kotlin REPL.

Following [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html#running-the-repl), and considering I am using OS X, and I have tried this:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/kotlinc-jvm
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$ kotlinc-jvm
```

Then in [the following link](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/nice-way-to-launch-the-kotlin-repl/1602), I found that a nicer way to run it is:

```
$ kotlinc
```

Is there any differences between this two commands, and which one should I choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look inside the `kotlinc-jvm` files, they actually just launch the `kotlinc` that's in the same folder they are in, and pass any arguments they were started with to it:

`kotlinc-jvm` for Unix:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# (License here)

DIR="${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}"
: ${DIR:="."}

"${DIR}"/kotlinc "$@"
```

`kotlinc-jvm.bat` for Windows:

```
@echo off

rem (License here)

call %~dps0kotlinc.bat %*
```

I'm not sure why `kotlinc-jvm` is there in this form, it's basically just a very simple redirect. I'd just use `kotlinc`.