# Are Kotlin and Java runtimes the same thing?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm

I've been wondering, when I compile Kotlin code with `kotlinc-jvm` and produce bytecode, I can run it with both `java` command and `kotlin` command as well. So my question is, is there any difference between those two runtimes, or are they the same thing ?

Also, are `kotlinc` and `kotlinvc-jvm` the same thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run the Kotlin REPL kotlinc-jvm or kotlinc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093527/how-can-i-run-the-kotlin-repl-kotlinc-jvm-or-kotlinc)

Answer (score 0):

kotlinc is a script that defaults compilation to kotlinc-jvm. If there are no arguments kotlinc starts a REPL.

When you comple kotlin with either of them the compiler produces classes in bytecode from your sources, including java sources for a mixed project and aims for the JVM. The runtime is the same, and includes any default kotlin libraries.

There are alternative runtimes and compilers. kotlinc-js and kotinc-native.

Comment: could you provide any documentation that supports your answer?